# .split() does not split all the words in a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, split

Here is the exercise:
"Write a program that categorizes each mail message by
which day of the week the commit was done. To do this look for lines
that start with “From”, then look for the third word and keep a running
count of each of the days of the week. At the end of the program print
out the contents of your dictionary (order does not matter).
Sample Line:
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat Jan 5 09:14:16 2008"
I need these kinds of lines be splited from my file but in output just zero and first positions (From and the email address) are shown not other words. The error in output is: "list index is out of rage".
Here is my code:

```
file1= open('short.txt')
counts= dict()
for line in file1:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if not line.startswith('From: '): continue
    splited = line.split()
    print(splited)
    day= splited[2]
    counts[day]= counts.get(day,0)+1
print('Count of days:',counts)
```

Comment: post your ```short.txt``` file txt

Comment: www.py4e.com/code3/mbox-short.txt

Comment: Edit a few lines of your short.txt into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for the lines starting with `From:` while the line which you want starts with `From` , I think below code should work for you:

```
counts = {}
with open('short.txt') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('From '):
            day = line.split()[2]
            counts[day] = counts.get(day ,0) + 1    
print (counts)
```

Output:

```
{'Sat': 1, 'Fri': 20, 'Thu': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please make yourself familiar with the mailbox file format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox , your input file is probably some variant of it.

The "From" line you want to parse contains `"From "` without a semicolon and it is at the beginning of a saved message.

The `"From: "` line (with a semicolon) is part of the message headers and has a different syntax - it contains an address, not a date. The headers are separated from the message body by a blank linke. You should move on to the next message at the blank line.